# Using variable in library dependency path in .NET

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-6.0, csproj

I'm developing a `.NET 6` `C#` application, and I have some projects in the solution that depend on an external DLL library.

What I would like is being able to use a variable in the path to the library reference in the .csproj file. I thought you could do something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LibVer>v1.2</LibVer>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="MyLibrary">
        <HintPath>..\libs\${LibVer}\MyLibrary.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

However, this doesn't work, as soon as I do it the project doesn't compile anymore. I don't get any specific error in the compilation output, all I get is that any type from the included library is not recognized, with the classic error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'XXXXX' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can this be done? If so, what is the correct way?

(some context as to motivation: I have several different versions of this dependency and I would like to be able to change just one variable in a common .csproj file and have all the solution's projects that include the dependency load the correct one)

Comment: You can build a nuget package which contains the external library and reference that nuget packed with a specific version

Comment: Could you explain some more about the purpose? In some cases it might be better to use [AssemblyResolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/resolve-loads) to select a version to load at runtime.

Comment: Would help if you describe why you need different versions while editing and not just at runtime.

Comment: @Ralf: I have requirements to compile the app against different versions of the library (for example to test compatibility with new versions of the library, or produce specific builds for specific clients that require a specific version). Basically, my goal is to change the path in one place, instead of having to do it in every project that includes the library

Comment: Why exactly do you want to switch back to older versions? If the DLL is tracked in a git repo you could use that for updates and roll-backs. Also you didn't explain where `${LibVer}` is coming from. You probably meant `$(LibVer)` which would be a custom MSBuild property.

Comment: It sounds like you want to define the desired version as an [MSBuild property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties). There are multiple ways to do that. How exactly are you building/deploying releases? Do you have CI/CD pipeline?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride: that was it! I'm stupid, I was using `{}` instead of `()`... it now works. PS: the reasoning is that I have different company departments asking me for builds with different versions of the dependency and I don't want to change the inclusion in all project files every single time.

Comment: @JonasH: thanks for making me aware of that feature, I didn't know of it, will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out it was just a dumb typo on my end, I was using braces instead of brackets.

This works correctly:

```
<HintPath>..\libs\$(LibVer)\MyLibrary.dll</HintPath>
```